# Are there lower class men in The Handmaid's Tale who are not law enforcement/military?

Tags: the-handmaids-tale

Are there men (who have not been exiled to the colonies) in Gilead who are not law enforcement or military (guardians/angels) and not part of the ruling elite (e.g. commanders)? If so are any of these named characters?

Comment: The duplicate target mentions `Men – "regular" men of lower classes; can marry Econowives and hold regular jobs` so the answer to your question is yes there are.